# Editing "tweet this" button to tweet only part of the page title

Tags: javascript, twitter, share, page-title

My blog formats all page titles like so: "Article Title | Slacktory | That seems legit."

Currently, Twitter's official "tweet this" button, from any single-post page, formats a tweet to include that entire title.

How can I edit the code so it omits the " | Slacktory | That seems legit." portion, leaving only the unique page title?

If there's any relevant information in [Twitter's tweet button documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button), I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the `data-text` attribute on the `<a>` to your title.

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" data-text="Article Title">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! But does that work on a site-wide basis? That is, if the "tweet this" button code is on the template for every single-post page, is there a value for the data-text variable that will detect the post title on any given page? (Am I correct in assuming that entering the code exactly as you wrote it would mean every tweet would have the actual text "Article Title" and not an actual article title?)

Comment: `data-text="<?php echo addslashes($title); ?>"` - problem solved?